# free_result needed by reuse variable

Tags: php

```
INCLUDE mysqli object

--

$sel = $mysqli->query("select * from `items`");
while($res = $sel->fetch_assoc()) {
$items[] = $res;
}
$sel->free_result();

$sel = $mysqli->query("select * from `sets`");
while($res = $sel->fetch_assoc()) {
$sets[] = $res;
}
$sel->free_result();

$sel = $mysqli->query("select * from `parts`");
while($res = $sel->fetch_assoc()) {
$parts[] = $res;
}
$sel->free_result();

--
DO OTHER STUFF
```

Are the first two times of executing `$sel->free_result();` really needed?
I think they are unnecessary when I reuse the variable `sel`.

Do you agree with me?

Comment: So your question is: does the query result continue to consume memory or is the query result overwritten, so memory is essentially "freed" with each successive query?

Comment: Yes, that is a my question.

Comment: This link may help you ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502201/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-mysql-free-resultresult

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php) on the matter:

> You should always free your result with `mysqli_free_result()`, when
>   your result object is not needed anymore.

Looking into the comments section of that page gives a reason why:

> If you are getting this error:  Internal SQL Bug: 2014, Commands out
>   of sync; you can't run this command now
>
> Then you never called mysqli_result::free(),
>   mysqli_result::free_result(), mysqli_result::close(), or
>   mysqli_free_result() in your script, and must call it before executing
>   another stored procedure.

Basically, you don't need to do it, but there could be odd instances where you're unable to execute other procedures, and commands could be out of sync.

Another issue which could come from not doing it is that the result could be taking up a lot of memory so if you put new code in between the queries which needs memory, then you could hit an issue where the script crashes due to being unable to allocate more memory.  By freeing the result you're helping to reduce the chances of this happening should you need to make changes between query executions.

At an extreme level, if you've got a bug in a different part of your system which can read other memory addresses and one of those queries has sensitive information stored in it, by not freeing the result, you're potentially giving an attacker a chance to read that sensitive information from memory.

There's bound to be other cases where there are issues, but those two sprung to mind.

In a nutshell, it's better to free the result and not have the information in memory when it's not needed.